# how to fetch array in different time slots

Tags: php, arrays, time, multidimensional-array

I have an two dimensional array like below:

```
array( array(), array(), array(), array(), array(), array() );
```

I have to access **0,1,2 indexed arrays** in time slot of 8 hours in day, if a user request value matches array value in first 8th hour slot then he will be get 3rd index array otherwise 0th indexed array, if same user request again in next 8th hour slot then he'll get 4 th indexed array. If there is new request which doesn't matched value in array then they get scheduled indexed array i.e

- from 12:00A.M to 8:00Am they get Array( 0 => array() ),
- from 8:00Am to 16:00PM they get Array( 1 => array() ),
- from 16:00Pm o 23:59PM they get Array( 2 => array() ).

I have implemented this using if else conditions but using hard cord timing conditions:

```
$params = array(); //main array

$pn = $_REQUEST['pn'];
$ad = new time_slot();

$time = date("H");
if ( $pn == $ad->ad_filter( $params, 0 ) ) { //ad_filter extract value from array and match request user value
        if ( $time < 8 ) {
            echo $ad->ad_data( $params, 1 ); //ad_data throw an array from multi-dimensional array 
        } else {
            echo $ad->ad_data( $params, 3 );
        }
    } elseif ( $pn == $ad->ad_filter( $params, 1 ) ) {
        if ( $time > 8 && $time < 16 ) {
            echo $ad->ad_data( $params, 2 ); //after 8 hour
        } else {
            echo $ad->ad_data( $params, 4 );
        }
    } elseif ( $pn == $ad->ad_filter( $params, 2 ) ) {
        if ( $time > 16 && $time < 24 ) {
            echo $ad->ad_data( $params, 0 ); //after 16 hour
        } else {
            echo $ad->ad_data( $params, 5 );
        }
    } elseif ( !in_array($pn, $ad->ad_filter( $params ))) { //if request is new
        if ( $time < 8 ) {
            echo $ad->ad_data( $params, 0 );
        } elseif ( $time > 8 && $time < 16 ) {
            echo $ad->ad_data( $params, 1 );
        } elseif ( $time > 16 && $time < 24 ) {
            echo $ad->ad_data( $params, 2 );
        } else {
            echo $ad->ad_data( $params, 3 );
        }
    }
```

But if have to throw array in only two slots i.e in 12 hours slot or in if in 4 hour slots then i have to code again conditions which is pathetic for me. So i created a function wrapper for this scenario:

count array using sizeof and loop it over all iterations as:

```
function array_scheduling( $params = array() ) {

    for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($params)/2; $i++) {
      if ($pn == $ad->ad_filter($params, $i)) {
        if ($time < (24/(sizeof($params)/2))*($i+1)) {
            echo $ad->ad_data( $params, $i++ );
        } else {
            echo $ad->ad_data( $params, $i+=3 );
        }
        } elseif (!in_array($pn, $params)) {
        echo $ad->ad_data( $params, $i );
        }
    }
}
```

This is only just a try, but it slightly not working because if user request value matches last array element value then i have to thrown first array. I can do this using `if/else` conditions successfully but in future for if there are more slots then how could i achieve it using a function which contains abstract definition.